# Restricting access to AWS resources to one specific region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to have my lambda full access restricted to a particular region.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "events:*",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "lambda:*",
                "logs:*",
                "s3:*"
                
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-east-1"
                }
        }       
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my policy.

but currently, it is not working user is still able to access lambda and it's full access in another region.

what am I missing here?

Comment: Which user? IAM user? Also the user may have other permissions, e.g. to access all lambda functions, in her/his IAM group, other policies.

Comment: @Marcin IAM user. Let me check the other policies attached to the group

Comment: are you attaching this policy to the Lamba's IAM role ?

Comment: no this is a user role, not a service role

Comment: So the the user group has other permissions which all the access? If so, for that user you would have to use `Deny` if `StringNotEquals`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66345518/application-load-balancer-https-listiner-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @Marcin ill get back on this current question when I try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IAM user(s) are probably allowed to perform your actions in different regions, because your policy is `Allow` only and they have other policies that allow unrestricted access.

To overcome the issue you can use `Deny` statement in the policy, as explained in [AWS: Denies access to AWS based on the requested Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-requested-region.html). `Deny` **always wins**, which means that the policy will have precedence over any allows.

So your policy, based on the AWS docs linked, could be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "events:*",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "lambda:*",
                "logs:*",
                "s3:*"
                
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-east-1"
                }
        }       
        }
    ]
}
```

Note, that in the AWS docs they also use `NotAction`, instead of `Action`. So you have to take into account what you wish your users to be able to do, or not do. But in your case, I think `Action` is fine.

Comment: could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327053/passing-an-dynamic-data-html-template-with-ses-lambda-notification