# Application load balancer HTTPS listiner not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb

I have set up ALB which is listening on both HTTP and HTTPS.
But the issue here is HTTP tariff is fetching a proper response and where as HTTPS is

[image]

What could be causing this?

Note:

I have added the same certificate to another lb and it is working fine.
to test I opened all the traffic and still getting it.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: It would be great if you could tell me how you are trying to access the web application. are you trying to access the web app by entering your domain name such as `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add SSL certificate to the ALB, you should be using **your own domain** for which the SSL certificate has been issued.

If you use AWS provided default domain for the ALB, you will get this error, since the SSL certificate **does not match** the AWS domain. Also you have no control over that domain and you can't get the SSL certificate for it.

You can try to setup redirect action from aws provided domain to your domain on the alb. One example of doing this is shown in:

- [How can I redirect one domain to another domain using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/)

Such rule would be something like below:

[image]

Comment: Marcin, as you pointed out the issue was the domain name of the SSL and Route53 mismatch :) . I was close

Comment: @sumanthshetty It happens. Glad it worked out at the end:-)

Comment: Could you help me out with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743113/sns-notification-target-rule-is-unreachable-when-tryin-to-send-a-notification