# SNS notification target rule is "unreachable" when tryin to send a notification from code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to set up a notification for the code pipeline using its notification rule which supporters SNS.

[image]

As you can see in the picture the status is "unreachable"

If I look at the link here [aws troubleshoot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-no-SNS)

I have followed all the step even the step of adding of codestar-notifications in Acces policy of SNS topic.

```json
{
      "Sid": "AWSCodeStarNotifications_publish",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:codestar-notifications:us-east-1:272075499248:notificationrule/50d629524d433dceeafdb6c5fe136e404f29e9e5"
    }
```

But still, the status remains the same also tried with manually starting the pipeline but still not working.

Am I missing something? could anyone help me out of this?

EDIT:

```json
 {
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:272075499248:develop",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "272075499248"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCodeStarNotifications_publish",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:272075499248:develop"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The resource in that policy should not be a codestar one but the SNS topic you want to grant access to.

Comment: @luk2302 I have made the necessary changes, I have replaced the correct resource ARN, but it still show the same status

Comment: Did you delete and recreate the rule target!?

Comment: I edited the access policy for the rule @luk2302

Comment: So no, you did not delete and recreate the rule target!? Do that. Delete and recreate it. I hope you did not edit the "access policy for the rule" because you need to edit the topic policy for the *topic*.

Comment: Your policy should have `"Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:272075499248:develop"`, not what you have now.

Comment: What Marcin said is what I said over an hour ago, did you still not put the proper **topic** in that policy?

Comment: @Marcin , if you look that the link, they have used the notification ARN

Comment: They use sns topic correctly. Maybe you misread it or looked at some other example?

Comment: @Marcin i have added the resource ARN but still it is unreachable

Comment: Did you delete the notification rule and re-created it as luk advised?

Comment: @Marcin i did, but no changes.

Comment: @luk2302 I am editing the topic access policy only. I also tried creating a new one but still no progress.

Comment: What does your topic policy look like right now?

Comment: @luk2302 have added the policy in the question

Comment: THAT IS STILL THE WRONG RESOURCE ARN - I give up. Please read the article you already linked and do **EXACTLY** what it says there.

Comment: @luk2302 Could you point out what exactly is wrong here?
I could see I am using "Resource": "arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:272075499248:test-loadeo" which is the right ARN

Comment: @luk2302 got it working

Comment: I faced the same issue. However, the cause was that I enabled encryption for the SNS topic which you should not do according to the [troubleshooting page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chatbot/latest/adminguide/chatbot-troubleshooting.html)

Answer (score 16):

### The previous answers here were too confusing and some of them were incomplete. Here is the complete solution with the ins and outs.

#### 1. Simple Notification Service Access Policy Confusion

Whenever you create an **SNS topic** by itself, the default access policy will look something like this:

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:my-sns-topic",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "123456789012"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is wrong and will not let your CodePipeline access the **SNS topic** (make it reachable/"Active")! Change the **Access policy** for your **SNS topic** to the following instead:

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "CodeNotification_publish",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:my-sns-topic"
    }
  ]
}
```

**NOTE 1**: Change `123456789012` to your AWS account ID, and `my-sns-topic` to the name of your **SNS topic**.
**NOTE 2**: If your region is different than `us-east-2`, then change that too in the above snippet.
**NOTE 3**: Both the **SNS topic** and the **CodePipeline Notification rule** should be in the same region, otherwise this won't work.

#### 2. Notification Rule and Notification Rule Target Issue

Whenever you create a **Notification Rule** and then a **Notification Rule Target**,
the only way possible for AWS to refresh the **Notification target status** is for you to delete the **Notification rule target** from `CodePipeline -> Settings (on the left side bar) -> Notification rules -> Notification rule targets` (this is extremely important!).

**NOTE**: Deleting the **Notification rule target** from the notification rule itself won't do anything; because of that, when you re-add it in that page, the **Notification rule target** will still be the old one and thus the **Notification target status** will remain "Unreachable".

If after everything it still says it's unreachable, repeat exactly steps #1 and #2 again, you may have missed something.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me by adding `"Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"` to "Principal" and performing step-2.

Comment: great answer! you saved my day. AWS should update the default access policy snippet.

Comment: Can you clarify point #2. You are saying that you should delete the notification rule target. But then you are saying that this won't do anything. So what exactly are you supposed to do?

Comment: @swbandit Sure. I was saying that deleting the notification rule target from the **notification rule itself** won't do anything, but if you delete from the **CodePipeline** tab, it will be effective.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to use the CodePipeline user interface to create the Topic.  This will set all of the required permissions for you.  When creating the Notification Rule, under "Targets", select "Create Target" and enter the name of the Topic you wish to create.  The topic will be created with permissions already set.  You will just need to subscribe to the topic to receive the notifications.

Comment: This was the easier solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON file is correct, but you should delete and re-create the target rule

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your pipeline’s IAM execution role doesn’t have the required permissions to publish messages to the topic. Make sure your pipeline can publish messages in both the IAM role and the SNS policy and give it another go. A telltale sign of this is the CodePipeline notification console showing “Unreachable” next to the SNS topic.

The SNS access policy will look like the following:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "StatusNotificationsPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:root",
            "Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:gimme-alerts"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
                "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
                "SNS:AddPermission",
                "SNS:RemovePermission",
                "SNS:DeleteTopic",
                "SNS:Subscribe",
                "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "SNS:Publish",
                "SNS:Receive"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:gimme-alerts",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceOwner": "123456789123"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

https://www.stephengream.com/codepipeline-notifications

Answer (score 0):

The following did work for me.

I followed the suggestion by Phil Gilligan in the other answer. It automatically created the access policy in sns topic when its created from CodeCommit itself.

Change the account id and repo name according to your own case.

There is no other rule just this one rule. It seems like the rules are evaluated and one rule overridden the other. I think if one rule is more restrictive it takes precedence over the other.

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "CodeNotification_publish",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:REPO_NAME"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers about *Access Policy* are right. But the change is not applied immediately. Very annoying.

Just create new topic from CodePipeline Settings. The access policy will be auto-adjusted.

Comment: In my case the changes applied immediately. But state changed to 'active' only after first notification was sent.